# which is the best technique for responsive flutter

Tags: flutter

creating responsive widget kinda isMobile?Fontsize 12 : fontsize 24 or use sizer package,what is the best responsive method for web,tablet,mobile?

Comment: I think we can skip scaling/sizing the font, while 12/14 is enough for to read. From my past experience of sizing, I might prefer theme for this like `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1`  You can check [Flutter how to create responsive Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57210428/10157127) and [adaptive vs responsive app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)

Comment: Opinion based questions are Off Topic for StackOverFlow

Answer (score 2):

flutter documentation did give some solution but , not effective for all purposes

```
AspectRatio
CustomSingleChildLayout
CustomMultiChildLayout
FittedBox
FractionallySizedBox
LayoutBuilder
MediaQuery
MediaQueryData
OrientationBuilder
```

if we using one by one , all methods have it's own **defects** .
mobile side and tablet side it will work , but in the case of windows and web , it won't.

if we combine these methods , also get some responsive issue , because of all methods are depend on the device height ,device width ,device aspectRatio , device Offset ,

also so much plugins are available but they have defects too , in the case of `flutter_screenutil` it depend on width , height . so if changes in one of the property it won't count. that means it won't change layout in web

so i am using this way combine 4 methods together
`flutter_screenutil , LayoutBuilder , MediaQuery , AspectRatio`
by using this way we can achieve,maintain the 3 layouts in one code

please use wisely according to your use case

Answer (score 0):

the best place to find FLUTTER solutions/documentations is the official flutter/dart websites. 
**For this question:**
[Creating responsive and adaptive apps](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)