# Prevent device display and font size from affecting app fonts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

I'm able to resolve in retaining the app's font size even thought the device is using bigger font size. My problem come along when the user also changes the display size or set the texts to bold that makes my apps font too enlarged.

[image]

Here's what I have for now..

***main.dart***

```
....
child: MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: 1.0,
      ),
      child: child!,
    );
  },
.....
```

How can I achieve my goal to also retain the font size even the user change the display size too?

Comment: then set values of ``fontSize`` and ``fontWeight``  !!

Answer (score 1):

I Apologise for the previous code, try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        final originalTextScaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
        final boldText = MediaQuery.boldTextOverride(context);

        final newMediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
          textScaleFactor: originalTextScaleFactor.clamp(0.8, 1.0),
          boldText: boldText,
        );

        return MediaQuery(
          data: newMediaQueryData,
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retain Font Size'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, The named parameter 'displaySizeFactor' isn't defined. I have already tried that.

Comment: @ramedju, try to use `MediaQuery.boldTextOf(context)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package. It will give resolve your issue.

Also check this [How to create responsive Text widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210428/how-to-create-responsive-text-widget-in-flutter) this may help you